# Indicate already delete voted posts in the 10k moderator tools

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

There needs to be a way to identify questions that have been delete voted on the deleted votes page of the 10k moderator tools.

It would be nice to see less of the text in the red box:

> [image]

I get it that each question needs to be viewed so it can be voted on. I have 5 votes a day, there are currently 100's of questions in the queue that need to be viewed, I can't remember from day to day which questions I've voted on and which ones I haven't. I am much less likely to actually use the modrator tools to clean up extremely bad questions if it is difficult to do, and I'm not the only one, as the review queue keeps going up from day to day.

Could we get an indicator in the delete votes 10k moderator tools to indicate if a question has already been voted on?

Something that looks like the image below? That says "Reviewed" or "Voted". A check mark would even suffice.

> [image]

The queues in some of the sites are quite large, I think this is partially because it is hard to vote to delete questions. At the end of the day, there needs to be some way for us who use the moderator tools to know what has been voted on and see less of the red box.

The duplicate mark is for a question that is six years old and nothing has been done. And mine is different because I made a suggestion of actual ways this could be implemented. There have been multiple requests for variations of something like this, an there have been zero comments from any of the powers that be that can actually change this to say yea or nay. I would like -- in the least that this be addressed in some way